# how to deploy Strimzi KafkaMirrorMaker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, strimzi

I am using strimzi operator and running kafka cluster on k8s.I want to use Kafka Mirror Maker ,I deployed Kafka Mirror Maker using CRD yml ,but my pod for KMM are in crashLoopBack status.I didn't get what the proble is?
Here is my Kafka MirrorMaker yml

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: KafkaMirrorMaker
metadata:
  name: my-mirror-maker
spec:
  version: 2.6.0
  replicas: 1
  consumer:
    bootstrapServers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    groupId: my-source-group-id
  producer:
    bootstrapServers: my-cluster2-kafka-bootstrap:9092
  whitelist: ".*"
```

and also my kafka-cluster yml :

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.6.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      log.message.format.version: "2.6"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 100Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

My second Kafka cluster:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster2
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.6.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      log.message.format.version: "2.6"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 100Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

My pod List and their status:

```
    strimzi       my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-d7gqg              1/1     Running   2          10m
strimzi       my-cluster-entity-operator-7b546bddfd-4622z    3/3     Running   0          6m51s
strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-0                             1/1     Running   0          9m26s
strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-1                             1/1     Running   2          9m26s
strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-2                             1/1     Running   2          9m26s
strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-0                         1/1     Running   0          10m
strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-1                         1/1     Running   1          10m
strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-2                         1/1     Running   0          10m
strimzi       my-cluster2-entity-operator-74f6f4dbc4-7jhvh   3/3     Running   0          7m52s
strimzi       my-cluster2-kafka-0                            1/1     Running   0          9m39s
strimzi       my-cluster2-kafka-1                            1/1     Running   0          9m39s
strimzi       my-cluster2-kafka-2                            1/1     Running   0          9m39s
strimzi       my-cluster2-zookeeper-0                        1/1     Running   0          10m
strimzi       my-cluster2-zookeeper-1                        1/1     Running   0          10m
strimzi       my-cluster2-zookeeper-2                        1/1     Running   0          10m
strimzi       my-connect-cluster-connect-6cdb6cd79d-qlnhg    1/1     Running   4          10m
strimzi       strimzi-cluster-operator-54ff55979f-sxrzq      1/1     Running   0          11m
```

Logs of Pod:

```
 ^Cist@ist-1207:~kubectl logs -f my-mirror-maker-mirror-maker-78544b8c8-rz5ms -n strimzi
    Kafka Mirror Maker consumer configuration:
    # Bootstrap servers
    bootstrap.servers=my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    # Consumer group
    group.id=my-source-group-id
    # Provided configuration



security.protocol=PLAINTEXT




Kafka Mirror Maker producer configuration:
# Bootstrap servers
bootstrap.servers=my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
# Provided configuration


security.protocol=PLAINTEXT




2020-11-20 11:41:38,990 INFO Starting readiness poller (io.strimzi.mirrormaker.agent.MirrorMakerAgent) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:39,176 INFO Starting liveness poller (io.strimzi.mirrormaker.agent.MirrorMakerAgent) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:39,604 INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,128 INFO Starting mirror maker (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [main]
WARNING: The default partition assignment strategy of the mirror maker will change from 'range' to 'roundrobin' in an upcoming release (so that better load balancing can be achieved). If you prefer to make this switch in advance of that release add the following to the corresponding config: 'partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor'
2020-11-20 11:41:40,301 INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = false
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,392 WARN Couldn't resolve server my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,393 INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer) [main]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,400 ERROR Exception when starting mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [main]
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:301)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerProducer.<init>(MirrorMaker.scala:370)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerOptions.checkArgs(MirrorMaker.scala:536)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:87)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:415)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:94)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
2020-11-20 11:41:40,410 INFO Start clean shutdown. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [MirrorMakerShutdownHook]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,413 INFO Shutting down consumer threads. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [MirrorMakerShutdownHook]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,413 INFO Closing producer. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [MirrorMakerShutdownHook]
2020-11-20 11:41:40,414 ERROR Uncaught exception in thread 'MirrorMakerShutdownHook': (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread) [MirrorMakerShutdownHook]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.cleanShutdown(MirrorMaker.scala:172)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerOptions.$anonfun$checkArgs$2(MirrorMaker.scala:522)
    at kafka.utils.Exit$.$anonfun$addShutdownHook$1(Exit.scala:38)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

this is svc of my kafka-clusters:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       kubernetes                       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      24m
kube-system   kube-dns                         ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       24m
strimzi       my-bridge-bridge-service         ClusterIP   10.108.118.142   <none>        8080/TCP                     11m
strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap       ClusterIP   10.109.128.192   <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   10m
strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-brokers         ClusterIP   None             <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   10m
strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-client      ClusterIP   10.110.172.185   <none>        2181/TCP                     11m
strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes       ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   11m
strimzi       my-cluster2-kafka-bootstrap      ClusterIP   10.105.92.74     <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   10m
strimzi       my-cluster2-kafka-brokers        ClusterIP   None             <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   10m
strimzi       my-cluster2-zookeeper-client     ClusterIP   10.98.76.46      <none>        2181/TCP                     11m
strimzi       my-cluster2-zookeeper-nodes      ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   11m
strimzi       my-connect-cluster-connect-api   ClusterIP   10.101.136.97    <none>        8083/TCP                     11m
```

Comment: I'd suggest MirrorMaker2 https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/master/using.html#assembly-mirrormaker-str

Comment: your error clearly say that the issue with bootstrap server . ERROR Exception when starting mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$) [main]
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer ..... No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers.  You need to make sure you provided the right bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Of course MM needs two clusters running in order to mirror them and I see just one named `my-cluster` while in the MM resource you are mirroring two clusters named `my-source-cluster` and `my-target-cluster` as stated in the bootstrap servers.
The only bootstrap server you have right now is `my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap` and anyway just one cluster is not enough for mirroring.

Comment: ok so can we create 2 kafka-clusters in one local machin ?

Comment: of course you can but it would be just for learning and development purposes. In general you want to mirror cluster across different data centers or maybe availability zones or even across two different cloud providers running Kubernetes.

Comment: Hey I created another cluster my-cluster two and also updated the MM yml but still I m getting some errors and the pod gone in crashloopbackoff status again.

Comment: can you double check that both kafka cluster are running and what are the services available in Kubernetes related to the two clusters?

Comment: I would say that Strimzi doc is the right place on how to use it in Strimzi https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/master/using.html#assembly-deployment-configuration-kafka-mirror-maker-str or even the official Kafka doc about mirror maker https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker

Comment: @ppatierno I am new to kafka MM ...I just wanted to deploy MM and understand how it works for learning purpose...I read that 2 kafka clusters are needed to use KMM ...please tell me what to do.I will also learn to use it to mirror one topic to another within the same cluster ....but right now I created two clusters and trying to deploy Kafka MM. But I am getting status as crashloopbackoff

Comment: @ppatierno I see svc and pod list ...both the clusters are running properly

Comment: As your MM log says `my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap` cannot be resolved, I would double check, if your MM configuration really is something like this 

`producer:`

  `bootstrapServers: my-cluster2-kafka-bootstrap:9092`

Comment: MM is trying to connect to `my-cluster2-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092` while your cluster 2 has bootstrap service `my-cluster2-kafka-bootstrap` so you are using a wrong bootstrap server in your MM configuration.